# Show that a Regular space $X$ is Lindelöf if it has a locally finite open cover $\mathcal{U}$ such that $\rm{Fr}\,U$ has the Lindelöf property

Tags: general-topology, lindelof-spaces

Show that if a regular space $X$ has a locally finite open cover $\mathcal{U}$ such that $\rm{Fr}\,U$ has the Lindelöf property for all $U\in\mathcal{U}$, then the space X is also a Lindelöf Space.

one suggestion for this exercise please?. I try of all but i don't have exit.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Suppose X is an uncountable discrete space.and let $\mathcal{U}$ be the family of all singletons of X. This is locally finite and each Fr U is empty and so trivially Lindelof, but X is not a Lindelof space.

Comment: Engelking has this as exercise 3.8.H, based on [this paper](https://msp.org/pjm/1975/59-1/pjm-v59-n1-p01-p.pdf), I think. But Lindelöfness is not a possible property $\mathcal{P}$ as in the paper or Engelking, as @DavidHartley 's simple example shows..

Comment: So @LuisPrado the statement is false as formulated; it cannot be proved (or maths has a problem :) )